# GAE Connection to SQL: password authentication failed for user 'postgres'

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, knex.js

nodejs app on GAE flex deploys correctly, but won't connect to postgres, even though initial knex migration worked and the tables were created. Ive read through the documentation and cant understand how all of the below can be true.

running `psql -h [ipaddress] -p 5432 -U postgres mydb` and entering the password from my local machine works!

package.json..

```
"prestart": "npx knex migrate:latest && npx knex seed:run
"start": "NODE_ENV=production npm-run-all build server"
```

worked! tables were created and seed was run
knexfile

```
production: {
  client: 'postgresql',
  connection: {
    database: DB_PASS,
    user: DB_USER,
    password: DB_PASS,
    host: DB_HOST

  },
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 10
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: './db/migrations',
    tableName: 'knex_migrations'
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: './db/seeds/dev'
  }
}
```

yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

instance_class: F2

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: xxxx-00000:us-west1:myinst

env_variables:
  DB_USER: 'postgres'
  DB_PASS: 'mypass'
  DB_NAME: 'myddb'
  DB_HOST: '/cloudsql/xxxx-00000:us-west1:myinst'

handlers:...
```

IAM

[image]

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Be careful, in your post (maybe correct in your code) you have `database: DB_PASS` (and not DB_NAME).

Comment: @ThierryFalvo is correct. Kindly hide or redact any sensitive information even if this is only a sample code.

Comment: Yes its supposed to say `process.env.DB_PASS` and obviously i just made up password in env variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oddly, it was a log only issue. the logs still say user authentication failed, but actually the app was connected.

Comment: Does this means your question is now resolved?

Comment: Yes, I suppose I should have checked more carefully before posting, but maybe this will be helpful to someone?